# Class / constructor to Action<T>?

Tags: c#, class, generics, constructor, delegates

I have two classes and they both inherit from Stream class.

```
FirstClass : Stream 
{
    FirstClass(Stream, CompressionMode) 
    {
         ..
    } 
}

SecondClass : Stream 
{
    SecondClass(Stream, CompressionMode) 
    {
         ..
    } 
}
```

I want to put one of these classes to a variable (Action i guess) and then make a new object from that variable – like this:

```
Action<Stream, CompressionMode> classPattern = condition ? FirstClass : SecondClass

///And now this
var newObject = classPattern(Stream, CompressionMode);

///Or maybe even this
classPattern newObject = classPattern(Stream, CompressionMode);
```

How do you that?

Thanks for help <3

Comment: `Action` is a `void` return type. You probably want a `Func`, where the last generic parameter is the return type.

Comment: I suggest implemening a *factory* class, say `public static class MyClassBuilder {public static Stream CreateMyClass(Stream parent, CompressionMode mode) {...}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt if you really want any lambda (`Func<Stream, CompressionMode, Stream>`) here. If you have many modes, conditions, options, labda will be too complex to maintain. I suggest *factory class*:

```
public static class MyClassBuilder {
  public static Stream Create(Stream parent, CompressionMode mode) {
    // Note, that we can easily include validation into factory's method  
    if (null == parent)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parent));

    return condition(mode, parent)  
      ? new FirstClass(parent, mode)
      : new SecondClass(parent, mode);
  }

  // It's easy to implement building with default mode:
  public static Stream Create(Stream parent, CompressionMode mode) =>
    Create(parent, CompressionMode.MaximumCompression);  
}
```

....

```
var newObject = MyClassBuilder.Create(someStream, someCompressionMode);

// with default CompressionMode
var otherObject = MyClassBuilder.Create(someOtherStream);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that you'll need a [`Func` delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?view=netcore-3.1) with two parameters

```cs
Func<Stream, CompressionMode, Stream> classPattern = (stream, mode) => condition ? (Stream)new FirstClass(stream, mode) : new SecondClass(stream, mode);
```

and use it

```cs
var newObject = classPattern(stream, compressionMode);
```

You may also convert it to a local function

```cs
Stream ClassPattern(Stream stream, CompressionMode mode) =>
    condition ? (Stream) new FirstClass(stream, mode) : new SecondClass(stream, mode);
```